# Iterating through in LinqToXml query

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml, xquery

As I haven't work yet with LinqToXml I'd like to ask you for help

Source XML:

```
<Projects xmlns="">
   <Project id="12345">
     <Name>AName</Name>
   </Project>
   <Project id="23456">
     <Name>BName</Name>
   </Project>
</Projects>
```

Linq query:

```
var q = (from xe in datasource.Descendants()
                 select new Data{ 
                                  ID = xe.Name.ToString(), 
                                  Name = xe.Value.ToString() 
                                }).ToList();
```

Output:

```
Project AName 
Name AName 
Project BName 
Name BName
```

Desired output:

```
12345 AName
23456 BName
```

So it seems that query is iterating through all descendants and takes `Name` as Node Name and `Value` as Node value. How should I modify it to get desired output? 
How about something like this:

- Get all `<Name>` nodes for iteration
- select `Value` of that node and `id` attribute for ancestor

P.S. Do you recommend any particular tutorials for LinqToXml?

Comment: For tutorials I suggest you to take a look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q = (from p in datasource.Descendants("Project")
         select new Data { 
               ID = (string)p.Attribute("id"), 
               Name = (string)p.Element("Name") 
         }).ToList();
```

Consider also to have `ID` property of integer type, then you will be able to parse it this way:

```
ID = (int)p.Attribute("id")
```

Also you can use methods (fluent) syntax:

```
var q = datasource
          .Descendants("Project")
          .Select(p => new Data { 
               ID = (string)p.Attribute("id"), 
               Name = (string)p.Element("Name") })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Tremendous work, I've finally ended up with: `var q = (from xe in datasource.Descendants("Project")
                     select new ProjectData{ ID = xe.Attribute("id").Value.ToString(), Name = xe.Element("Name").Value.ToString() }).ToList();`

Comment: @AdrianK. `Value` property is already of string type. You don't need to call `ToString()`. And the best options is casting to string, because it will not throw exception if node is missing.

Comment: You're absolutely right! casting to string prevents exceptions? Didn't knew that! Thanks for all your help, man!

Comment: @AdrianK. yep, if node is missing, `null` will be returned. But if you will try to access `someNode.Value` you will get `NullReferenceException` for missing node